# Why am I getting the value from another key

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my data structure. I only want to get the "regular" key from the first key which is the `-LZHfDw9kqC-3rBf4VRh`

[image: regular key]

Here is my code:

```
String rates = null;
DataSnapshot ratesSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child(key).child("promos");
Adapter_RoomsModel roomsModel = new Adapter_RoomsModel();
for (DataSnapshot ds : ratesSnapshot.getChildren()) {
  rates = ds.getKey();
  roomsModel.setRateName(rates);
}
```

My output :

```
-LZHfDw9kqC-3rBf4VRh
   regular
-LZQu0HReRqMhbnWgFJg
   regular
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected.  If you want only a single child value, your query will have to give the entire path to that location.  For example, you will need to call out `promos/-LZHfDw9kqC-3rBf4VRh/regular`.  You can't use wildcards.

If you don't know the name of a node, perhaps because it's a random push ID, then you need to query those children for the one(s) you want.

Comment: Yup it is working but i'm still getting the regular from the another key which is `-LZQu0HReRqMhbnWgFJg` , So i'll use `promos/key`? to get all the values from the specific key?

Comment: Oh i get it. So I can't retrieve only one regular?

Comment: Not unless you know it's full path, or a way to query for it with a unique value.

Comment: Any suggestion on how can I retrieve it?

Comment: I can't write your queries for you - my suggestions are in my answer above.

Comment: I'll change the data structure then. Can you help me with this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929771/how-can-i-query-to-get-the-2-values-from-different-child?noredirect=1#comment96625731_54929771)